# Records goes on duplicating

Tags: iphone

I am hitting the URL and getting data using JSON parsing. The URL is given hit on the Scrolling the items in ScrollView. the selected country's short from  in currency notation is given the the URL. but when the user scrolls faster the URL hits are increasing and the data collected goes on duplicating and the records parsed using the JSON is found to be duplicated.
The URL i am hitting is as follows. http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?from=%@&to=%@ the 2 parameters passed to the URL is scrollView Item and the other is the rest of the Countries shortForm for getting the data.

Comment: please give some code how you store the json data.

Comment: NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *dic = [jsonString JSONValue];

Comment: are you storing data in array or not?

Comment: yes i am storing the data in array.

Comment: if your problem is solved then accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

Please do empty your array before add data in array. Like.

```
   [myarray removeAllObjects];
```

OR

if you stored shareObject in array then:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < [myarray count]; i++) {
          ShareClass *shareObj = [myarray objectAtIndex:i];
          [shareObj release];
          shareObj = nil;
      }
      [myarray removeAllObjects];
```